# Attribute error: 'function' error has no attribute 'play' (on tkinter and pygame)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pygame

I'm new and i'm trying to do a program that plays different sounds according to what random number I get. I used *tkinter* to make a window.
This is my program. I don't understand why the command `.play()` does not work. I tried to put it as an attribute like `def son1 (play):` but it was useless. I tried many things but those did not succeed. Also I'm not a pro at all and I don't have a perfect English. I live in France and not many people have a good level on coding and I tried reading the doc but it was too hard. Anyway, thank you for your help.

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox
import pygame
import random

def son1 ():#function that plays a sound (son1)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    global son1
    son1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Gun_Cocking.wav")
    son1.play()
def son2 ():#function that plays a sound (son2)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    global son2
    son2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Gunshot.wav")
    son2.play()
def gachette():#if r=1 son2 plays, if r!=1 son1plays
    global son1, son2
    r=random.randint(1,6)
    if r==1:
        label1.configure(text="BAM! T'as tiré hahahaha, t'es ded!",font=("Comic Sans Ms",18),foreground="red")
        son2.play()
        bouton01.destroy()
    else:
        label1.configure(text="Clic! T'as survécu, tu continues hahaha" )
        son1.play()

fenetre=tkinter.Tk()
fenetre.title("La roulette russe")
fenetre.geometry("600x600")
fenetre.configure(background="black")
espace_dessin=tkinter.Canvas(fenetre,background="black", height=600, width=600)
espace_dessin.pack()
label0=tkinter.Label(fenetre,text="JEU DE LA ROULETTE RUSSE",font=("Arial",20),foreground="black")
label0.configure(background="white")
label0.pack()
label0.place(x=115,y=20)

label1=tkinter.Label(fenetre, text="T'es toujours vivant, félicitations...!", font=("Comic Sans Ms",18),foreground="green")
label1.configure(background="black")
label1.pack()
label1.place(x=110,y=200)

label2=tkinter.Label(fenetre, text="Tu poses le bout du canon sur ta tempe et ...", font=("Arial",18),foreground="grey")
label2.configure(background="black")
label2.pack()
label2.place(x=70,y=300)

bouton01=tkinter.Button(fenetre,text="Tirer",command=gachette,font=("Arial",16),relief="groove")
bouton01.pack()
bouton01.place(x=260,y=350)


fenetre.mainloop()
```

and here is my error messsage:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "C:\MCNL\Apps\Maths\EduPython\App\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1538, in __call__
>    return self.func(*args)
>  File "D:\Users\Diana VOLF\Desktop\rouletterusse\rouletterusse.py", line 27, in gachette
>    son1.play()
> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'play'
> ```

Comment: The function `son1` and the object `son1` have the same name. The function covers the object. You have to use different names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now !!

Answer (score 0):

The functions `son1`, `son2` and the object `son1`, `son2` have the same name. The function covers the object. You have to use different names:

```py
def son1():#function that plays a sound (son1)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    global sound1
    sound1 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Gun_Cocking.wav")
    sound1.play()
def son2 ():#function that plays a sound (son2)
    pygame.mixer.init()
    global sound2
    sound2 = pygame.mixer.Sound("Gunshot.wav")
    sound2.play()
def gachette():#if r=1 son2 plays, if r!=1 son1plays
    global sound1, sound2
    r=random.randint(1,6)
    if r==1:
        label1.configure(text="BAM! T'as tiré hahahaha, t'es ded!",font=("Comic Sans Ms",18),foreground="red")
        sound2.play()
        bouton01.destroy()
    else:
        label1.configure(text="Clic! T'as survécu, tu continues hahaha" )
        sound1.play()
```